# how can I reference Zend_Db_Table_Row properties inside it's object

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got a problem, im using Zend_Db_Table_Row to model my application. 
I have an object with a money property called value. It is storred as int in the database.
What i want to do, is to return Zend_Currency object each time something calls for this property. Like this:

```
$prepayment = Zend_Db_Table_Row
$currency = $prepayment->value; // should fetch Zend_Currency instead of plain int.
```

I've tried to acces $this->value inside Row class but it seems not work. How can I overwrite getters for an property inside Row object? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a view helper to convert your int value to a a Zend_Currency before displaying it :

```
class My_Helper_Currency extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{

    public function currency($value, $locale = 'fr_FR') {
        $currency = new Zend_Currency($locale);

        $value= $value+ 0.00;//to convert it to float

        return $currency->toCurrency((float) $value);

    }
}
```

and to display it in your view do :

```
 echo $this->currency($my_value);
```